# What is China's version of SEC/Edgar?

Tags: sec, china, annual-report

I use this page in the SEC ([SEC Edgar Company Search](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch)) to search for annual reports (10-Ks) for companies in the US.

What is the equivalent url that I would go to **search for Chinese companies**? For example, 600519 Kweichow Moutai. Please don't link me to http://www.csrc.gov.cn/csrc_en/index.shtml, this is their SEC if im understanding correctly, but there is no box to search for a Chinese listed company.

Bonus points if you can link me to a directory of all the SEC Edgar Equivalents for all the  [Developed Markets](https://www.msci.com/our-solutions/indexes/market-classification) according to MSCI!

Comment: You're assuming such a thing exists. Most stock exchanges and most countries don't actually have anything like that. In most cases reports are free form, published to the stock exchange, and are available from the companies themselves. I'm not familiar with China specifically, but from my experience the US SEC with its rigid codified forms is quite exceptional. See also [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/153522/yearly-reports-of-swiss-publicly-traded-companies?rq=1)

Comment: This is HK's equivalent: https://www1.hkexnews.hk/search/titlesearch.xhtml
I've seen similar ones in Canada and European countries I believe. Maybe Australia as well. So i dont think its that outlandish of a question.

Comment: The HK one is owned by the exchange itself. You can check whatever the exchange that listed that company in China (may be that very same HK exchange actually). Also, worth pointing out that search by document type is limited until 2007 in HK, so no, it doesn't actually exist there *anymore*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can read Chinese, since the quarterly/annual reports are in Chinese only anyway, here are the official pages from the exchanges

Shanghai Stock Exchange
http://www.sse.com.cn/disclosure/listedinfo/regular/
(You can search for 600519 here)

Shenzhen Stock Exchange
http://www.szse.cn/disclosure/listed/fixed/index.html

Comment: You could try machine translation if those pages. Results not guaranteed to be accurate, though.

Comment: Amazing thank you. And they have the english version on the top right corner! http://english.sse.com.cn/markets/equities/announcements/